# Request objects and response object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In express.js, middlewares can change request object and response object. So, my question is what exactly these request object and response object are and what do they contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same questions when i started with express. I found a nice article, explaining my questions.

http://www.murvinlai.com/req-and-res-in-nodejs.html

**UPDATE**

from the page:

> What is Req & Res?
>
> Req -> Http (https) Request Object.
>
> - You can get the request query, params, body, headers and cookies from it.
> - You can overwrite any value or add anything there.
> - However, overwriting headers or cookies will not affect the output back to the browser.
>
> Res -> Http (https) Response Object.
>
> - The response back to the client browser.
> - You can put new cookies value and that will write to the client browser (under cross domain rules)
> - Once you `res.send()` or `res.redirect()` or `res.render()`, you cann do it again, otherwise, there will be uncaught error.

Comment: Just note that since sites can go down, it's always preferred to summarize the contents of externally linked pages, so that answers on StackOverflow can standalone.  Also, to improve the discoverability of an answer via search, the true contents of that answer need to be present within the answer.

Comment: @ctt Thank you. That's a good hint. I'll remember it in my future posts.

Answer (score 4):

From expressjs documentation a [request](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) is:

> The req object represents the HTTP request and has properties for the request query string, parameters, body, HTTP headers, and so on.

And the [response](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res):

> he res object represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request.

Basically you use a **request** to know **what the client is asking for**.

And you use the **response** object to **send the** response **data to the client**.

Answer (score 1):

Me too had this same doubts.

**Request Object**
The req object represents the HTTP request and has properties for the request query string, parameters, body, HTTP headers, and so on

**Response Object**
The res object represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request.

Reference [Link](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req)